# Mysql procedure insert into temporary table

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have written a mysql procedure. I want into a temporary table using different select statement. While creating procedure its showing syntax error near at  '

```
SELECT
    value as last
FROM
    wp_13_rg_lead
    LEFT JOIN wp_13_rg_' at line 18
```

Below is my procedure

```
DELIMITER $$ 

CREATE  PROCEDURE TEMP_JOIN_WORK () 

BEGIN 

start transaction; 



    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP_JOIN(firstname varchar(500)     not null,lastname varchar(500) not null) ;

    insert into TEMP_JOIN(SELECT 
        value
    FROM 
        wp_13_rg_lead 
        LEFT JOIN wp_13_rg_lead_detail on wp_13_rg_lead.id = wp_13_rg_lead_detail.lead_id 
    WHERE 
        wp_13_rg_lead.form_id = 9 
        AND CAST(wp_13_rg_lead_detail.field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(1.3 AS DECIMAL) , 
    SELECT 
        value as lastname
    FROM 
        wp_13_rg_lead 
        LEFT JOIN wp_13_rg_lead_detail on wp_13_rg_lead.id = wp_13_rg_lead_detail.lead_id 
    WHERE 
        wp_13_rg_lead.form_id = 9 
        AND CAST(wp_13_rg_lead_detail.field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(1.6 AS DECIMAL)

     );

    SELECT * FROM TEMP_JOIN; 



    commit; 

    END 

    $$ 

    DELIMITER;
```

Comment: Your table design has some problems.  You shouldn't have to obtain the first and last name in this way using two different queries.  The issue here is that the _relation_ between the first and last name in the table is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

This should not give syntax error. In workbench, click on create stored procedure and copy the following between BEGIN  END.  Logic will work or not, that is a separate issue.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TEMP_JOIN(firstname VARCHAR(500)     NOT NULL,lastname VARCHAR(500) NOT NULL) ;

    INSERT INTO TEMP_JOIN VALUES((SELECT 
        `value`
    FROM 
        wp_13_rg_lead 
        LEFT JOIN wp_13_rg_lead_detail ON wp_13_rg_lead.id = wp_13_rg_lead_detail.lead_id 
    WHERE 
        wp_13_rg_lead.form_id = 9 
        AND CAST(wp_13_rg_lead_detail.field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(1.3 AS DECIMAL)) , (
    SELECT 
        `value` AS lastname
    FROM 
        wp_13_rg_lead 
        LEFT JOIN wp_13_rg_lead_detail ON wp_13_rg_lead.id = wp_13_rg_lead_detail.lead_id 
    WHERE 
        wp_13_rg_lead.form_id = 9 
        AND CAST(wp_13_rg_lead_detail.field_number AS DECIMAL) = CAST(1.6 AS DECIMAL))

     );

    SELECT * FROM TEMP_JOIN;
```